# Promise resolved before entire chain of promises is resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have a chain of promises as a function in my app. Each of my service functions returns a `deferred.promise`;

Considering the following scenario I have where main getUser service calls getUserPreferences and getUserFavourites asynchronously, the console.log after resolving getUserData is being resolved before getUserFavourites even responds! Shouldn't the promise in getUserData be resolved once getUserFavourites  responds?

In fact 'got all user data' from the console.log is in the console before getUserFavourites is called. Literally straight after getUser responds almost like `getUserData().then(` only resolves the top level promise and make the underlying 2 asynchronous...

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
var user = 'blabla';

function getUserData() {

   var deferred = $q.defer();

   getUser(user).then(
       function(response) {
          getUserPreferences(response.user).then(
             function(preferences) {
                console.log('preferences', preferences); 
             },
             function() {
                deferred.reject();
             }
          );

          getUserFavourites(response.user).then(
             function(favourites) {
                deferred.resolve();
                console.log('favourites', favourites);
             },
             function() {
                deferred.reject();
             }
          );
       },
       function() {
          deferred.reject();
       }
    );

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

```
getUserData().then(
   function() {
      console.log('got all user data');
   }
);
```

Comment: As unlikely as it sounds... is your console.log for faovurites after your deferred.resolve(); the problem? If you swap those around does it do what you're expecting?

Comment: @MathewBerg, no, that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must RETURN the nested promise in order to have a chain.
The problem here is you have 2 nested promises so you will need to return a Promise.all (or $q.all in your case) taking an array of the 2 promises returned by `getUserPreferences` and `getUserFavorites`:

```js
var user = 'blabla';

function getUserPreferences(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve({color: 'green'});
    },500);
  });
}

function getUserFavorites(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve([{id: 1, title: 'first favorite'}, {id: 2, title: 'second favorite'}]);
    },500);
  });
}

function getUser(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve(user);
    },500);
  });
}

function getUserData() {
   
   return getUser().then(
       function(user) {
          console.log(user);
          var prefPromise = getUserPreferences(user).then(
             function(preferences) {
                console.log('preferences', preferences); 
                return preferences;
             },
             function(error) {
                console.log("Error getting preferences");
                throw error;
             }
          );

          var favPromise = getUserFavorites(user).then(
             function(favourites) {
                console.log('favourites', favourites);
                return favourites;
             },
             function(error) {
                console.log("Error getting favorites");
                throw error;
             }
          );
          
          return Promise.all([
            prefPromise,
            favPromise
          ]);
       },
       function(err) {
          console.log("Error getting user");
          throw err;
       }
    );
}

getUserData().then(
   function(results) {
      console.log(results);
   }
);
```

Note that for demo purpose I am using es6 Promise instead of angular $q but the spirit is the same:

```
$q.defer() => new Promise()
$q.all     => Promise.all
```

As the Promise pattern is great to simplify async code and make it look like synchronous code, you can simplify the upper example with something like:

```js
var user = { name: 'blabla'};

function getUserPreferences(user){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve({color: 'green'});
    },500);
  });
}

function getUserFavorites(user){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve([{id: 1, title: 'first favorite'}, {id: 2, title: 'second favorite'}]);
    },500);
  });
}

function getUser(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return resolve(user);
    },500);
  });
}

function getUserData() {
   return getUser()
   .then(user => { // user is resolved
      // running parallel promises to get user infos:
      return Promise.all([
        user,
        getUserPreferences(user),
        getUserFavorites(user)
      ]);
    })
    .then(results => {
      // wrapping the results into something more semantic:
      let userData = results[0]; 
      userData.prefs = results[1];
      userData.favs = results[2];
      return userData;
    });
}

getUserData().then(
   function(userData) {
      console.log('Final result:');
      console.log(userData);
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to fix that is to use the `async/await` to make the code look synchronous.

```
var user = 'blabla';

async function getUserData() {

  try {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    let userInfo = await getUser(user)
    let userPrefs = await getUserPreferences(userInfo.user)
    console.log('preferences', userPrefs);

    let userFavourites = await getUserFavourites(userInfo.user)
    deferred.resolve();
    console.log('favourites', userFavourites);
    return deferred.promise;
  } catch (error) {
    deferred.reject();
  }
}

getUserData().then(
   function() {
      console.log('got all user data');
   }
);
```

Comment: 2 problems with this solution: 1. he is using angular so using async can become cumbersome, 2. this code is not executing getUserPreferences and getUserFavorites in parallel.

Comment: The ES6 promise returned by `async`/`await` are not integrated with the AngularJS framework. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$q.all` to return a composite promise:

```
function getUserData() {    
    return getUser(user).then(function(response) {
        var preferencesPromise = getUserPreferences(response.user);
        var favouritesPromise =  getUserFavourites(response.user);
        return $q.all([preferencesPromise, favouritesPromise]);
    });
}
```

Then extract the data from the composite promise:

```
getUserData().then([preferences, favourites] => {
    console.log('got all user data');
    console.log(preferences, favourites);
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

The `$q.all` method returns a single promise that will be resolved with an array/hash of values, each value corresponding to the promise at the same index/key in the promises array/hash. If any of the promises is resolved with a rejection, this resulting promise will be rejected with the same rejection value.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all)

Comment: In my case getUserData favourites is undefined because it takes longer than preferences. Not sure why but once getUser is resolved it doesn't wait for the following two promises...